# Is the Wolfram Server disabling Desktop Mathematica?

Tags: system

Earlier I got this in response to 2+2
[image]

I had to terminate it with task manager. Right now I'm trying to access FinancialData. In response to FinancialData["CAT"], the kernel has been running for 15 minutes -- still no response.

I'm on the current 11.1.1.0 and Win 7 x64.

Does anyone have an answer to this?

Comment: If your screen grab is literal the grey box indicates that you do not have dynamic updating enabled so that may be interfering with the updating.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. That may be it. I found that if I abort the FinancialData operation and then re-evaluate it, it functions normally on the second try.

Comment: I had a similar problem this morning. It just hung on the evaluation of `2+2`. I didn't see any message about updating from WR servers. But, I had dynamic updating enabled. It started working again after I disabled dynamic updating. Then, I got an internal self test error (something about the Kernel, don't remember exactly what the code was) when I opened the Documentation Center. Something weird is going on.